# WP JSON API Connect

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

i want to post content to wordpress from other php app. i am using rest api plugin for posting and for authentication i am using oath plugin.i just want to know how to get the access token .i am referring

https://github.com/WebDevStudios/WDS-WP-JSON-API-Connect

for the json_url in the code i use

eg(http://myproject.info/wpsingle/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/json-rest-api/lib/wp-json.php)

ends up in error.

> [errors] => Array ( [wp_json_api_connection_failed_error] => Array (
>   [0] => There was a problem connecting to the API URL specified. ) )
>   [error_data] => Array ( )

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://wp-api.org/) for the same thing. I used basic authentication. i.e. admin panel username and password for authentication. Because I was the only person who was going to post to wordpress. And the correct URL to access end point was like below

http://domain.com/wp-json/posts?filter[s]=awesome

[this](http://wp-api.org/#posts_create-a-post) is the link to how to create a post. I used Guzzle to call api like below to get a posts from particular category.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get("http://domain.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=test", array('auth' => ['username','password']));
$posts = $response->json();
```

But, If you are going to let other people post than you must use OAuth. Because you can not share admin panel username and password with everyone.

Comment: did you have any idea on how to implement oauth?

Comment: It's quite big to post here. But the link is here. It may not exactly what you want. But you may get idea. http://www.sitepoint.com/wp-api-and-oauth-using-wordpress-without-wordpress/

Comment: my requirement is an external application(php app) can access to wordpress. for security reason i am using oauth.i develop a plugin which can generate consumer key and secret in the word press . i use oauth plugin and wp rest api plugin.next step i need to get access token.can you show me a php code where i put the key and secret so that they give me an access token also i want to redirect to wordpress and return back.after that i can post delete edit  things from wordpress. pls help .actually i got stuck 3 weeks for this silly thing